# Rotate an object or change the culled face?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es-2.0

In OpenGL which one would result in a better performance. To change the culled face or to rotate my object?

The scenario is the following:

I compute the matrix to feed into my shaders, this will draw texture A in a certain culling position (front). When I see the object from infront i can see it, but from behind i cant, this is my desired behavior. Now i would like to add "something" behind, lets say texture B, so that when the object is seen from behind this other texture will appear in the same position and orientation as was the texture A but now with texture B.

I thought that other than building a cube with 2 sides i could simply "redraw on top" of my previous object. If i were to rotate the object i suppose I can assume that OpenGL will simply not overwrite texture A since it will not pass the face culling test. This require one extra matrix multiplication to mirror mi object on its own axis. However what if i simply change the culling property and try to draw it? Wouldn't it have the same effect of failing the text from infront but passing it from behind?

Which of these 2 options is better?

(PD: I am doing this on the iPhone so every single bit of performance is quite relevant for older devices.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but it sounds like you are trying to draw a billboard here? In that case, you should disable backface culling altogether and in your fragment shader check [`gl_FrontFacing`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/gl_FrontFacing.xml). Depending on this, you can flip your texture coordinates and change your texture (just bind both textures and send them to the shader). This way you have only one draw call and don't have to do any strange tricks or change the OpenGL state.

Comment: According to your reference page, it doesnt seem to be available for opengl es 2.0.

Comment: @LuisOscar It's marked with a `Y` for me?! Keep in mind that this is the GLSL ES manpage, not the GL ES manpage! Also, I'm not 100% certain, but pretty sure that I already used it in an ES 2 project.

Comment: this worked, thank you very much. Im just a bit concerned with the performance, wouldnt having a check in each of the fragment shaders make it more gpu intensive than just changing the state once before each draw call? or instead of applying 1 multiplicative matrix per vertex?